# Missing panels in Xcode 4?

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, xcode4

So I built an app last year and based the framework off of the video tutorial shown by the woman from O'Reillys, Elisabeth Robson. I was trying to build a version using Xcode 4.0, but when she goes into the attributes tab, to change the type to NavController, I don't have that option in Xcode 4.0 Interface Builder.
Anyone else run into this issue, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen the video, but it sounds like you want View -> Utilities -> Identity Inspector.

It looks like you want to change the type of view controller associated with a tab bar item.

On the left side of the IB window is a list with "Placeholders" and "Objects". Your tab bar controller should be in there. Click the triangle to open it and you should see "Tab Bar" and something like "View Controller - Item 1", etc.

Click "View Controller - Item 1", then look at the Identity Inspector. At the top is "Custom Class", which you use to change the class of the controller.

Comment: That's where i am looking, since that's where it was before. But in the new version there's no option to change it. If you have the time go to this video and look around the 12:45 mark of this video.   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBnPfAtswgw

Comment: I've added more detail after watching the video.